# SCSS Modules Giving Flow error

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, flowtype

Updated to `Create React App 2` which supports css modules via the following import statement:

```
import styles from "./myStyles.module.scss";
```

However, `flow` is complaining saying this:

```
Importing from an untyped module makes it any and is not safe!
Did you mean to add // @flow to the top of ./myStyles.module.scss? (untyped-import)
```

This is what the `[options]` in my `.flowconfig` file looks like:

```
module.file_ext=.js
module.file_ext=.jsx
module.file_ext=.scss
```

I've also tried adding the following line:

```
module.file_ext=.module.scss
```

Comment: I don't think you want flow to process the .scss files at all.  If you remove the `module.file_ext` setting for .scss, what do you get?

Comment: @DaveMeehan when deleting that line I get a hoard of flow errors saying "cannot resolve module" for al of my scss files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use [`module.name_mapper.extension`](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-module-name-mapper-extension-string-string) to get it to map your SCSS files to some mocked module. (The flowtype docs even have an example for doing this same thing with .css files).

So you might use this config:

```
module.name_mapper.extension='scss' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/SCSSFlowStub.js.flow'
```

and in SCSSFlowStub.js.flow

```
export default Object;
```

Comment: doing this and running flow gets rid of erros associated with my `xxx.module.scss` imports but brings up new errors with my legacy `xxx.scss` imports, saying `cannot resolve module FILE_PATH/SCSSFlowStub.js`

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? With <PROJECT_ROOT> and everything?